# Why can't you have a static and non-static method with the same method signature in Java?

Tags: java

Doesn't really seem to make sense to me. Maybe someone can help me understand. It seems kind of silly that I have to switch around the order of my parameters to have this feature.

Answer (score 12):

Because Java allows to invoke a `static` method in a non-static manner, i.e. on an object of the class. So, if a class has `static` and `non-static` methods - `method()` of same signature, an invocation like this: `obj.method()` would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

Because:

```
class Example {

   void method () { }

   static void method () { }

   void example () {
      method();   // <- ambiguous
   }

}
```

So you either introduce a constraint that differentiates static and nonstatic calls in that context, e.g. require `Example.` before static calls, or you disallow identical signatures. The latter was chosen.

Note that in most cases if you find yourself wanting both a static and nonstatic method with the same signature, this could be a red flag of a possible design issue, or at least a suggestion that better names for your methods could be chosen.

If you're thinking of "switching around the order of your parameters" as a kludge, *definitely* reconsider. There is definitely room for general improvement if you are in that situation. I would raise some serious eyebrows if I ever saw code like that.